# How to read the end of image file stream in VB6

Tags: image, file, sockets, vb6

There is a code written by another programmer which I want to improve. The purpose of the module is to get a live image stream from camera and to display it in the picture window. It is doing it over the TCP IP connection. Here is how it is done
Get the

```
Private Sub DataArrival(ByVal bytes As Long)

Dim str As String
' check the socket for data 
camera.GetData str
Dim str As String

While InStr(str, Terminator) <> 0

**Do some processing and put only the data in the variable str

 str = Mid(str, index, 1000)
 lImgSize = lImgSize + Len(str)
 strImg = strImg + str

  If lImageSize >= 1614414 Then
            Dim fileno As Integer
            fileno = FreeFile()
            Open ".\Imagefile.txt" For Output As #intFileNo
            Print #fileno , strImg
            Close #fileno 

  End If

End Sub
```

I have an input image stream coming and converting it to string and I am calculating the size to check the end of the image to write it in to a file. But the hardcoded value does not guarantee the end of file always. Sometimes If the image size is little less than the size, my picture box is not update with a live image.

EDIT:
This is what the image.txt file contains.

```
1
1575020 // file size header
424D36040C0000000000360400002800000000040000000300000100080000000000000000000000
--data--
--data--
020303030203010302010202030002030203020302020302030202030102
3BFB
```

Is there any other efficient way to handle this in VB6?

Comment: Seems like a dangerous way to determine if the image is complete. Is there no way the completion is signalled. How is the image data transferred to you?

Comment: Edit to include complete code, don't omit, please.

Comment: Data in a String is normally considered text and you are using text I/O operations too.  The conversions between Unicode and ANSI can result in all sorts of data coruuption on binary information, and at best you'll consume twice as much memory for your image data this way.

Comment: I agree that the sender should either be providing a length prefix header value or some out of band signal like a connection close.  Otherwise you are asking for magic.

Comment: @Bob77 I have totalfile size header sent by the receiver.But it includes only the size of data.

Comment: @ShivShambo Well what else is there? If you have the file size then just read that many bytes then switch back to reading the header. Oh, and NEVER store binary data in a VB string. Your sample seems to be hex encoded but you make no effort to decode it again.

Comment: @Deanna the data arrive in packets and Currently the image size value has been found out by debugging

Comment: @ShivShambo Yes, data will arrive in chunks, that's the nature of TCP. As the file size is sent before the file data itself, you just need to parse that out on the fly (depending ont he exact protocol) and then just keep reading data until you get that much data Wehn you do, you can close the connection or start looking for the file header again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to agree a full protocol that specifies how you're going to pass the image data and the image data length over the TCP stream.

In your receiver, you then start reading the data into a buffer until you get enough data to contain your headers. At this point, you can parse out the data length and then continue reading data into your data buffer until you at least that amount of data.
When you finally get all the data, you can decode and save out the image data then either close the stream (if it's a one off) or start form the beginning and parse out the file header.

You can find a bit more info on the [#VB wiki](http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/index.php/Designing_network_protocols#Receiving_data).