# vb6 Image receive through TCP. How to make it faster

Tags: windows, image, sockets, tcp, vb6

I am using vb6 to retrieve an image from a camera through TCP-IP, Now the receiving the image in bytes and writing it to text and convert to image format takes roughly about 9 seconds. **The total image size is around 1.6 mb and each packet size is 8192 bytes.** The another problem is the CPU utilisation which is 100%.

Now I am finding a way to make the image displaying faster and to reduce the CPU processing. Since VB cannot support multithreading. I have left with only few options.

I tried to increase the socket receive size from 8192 bytes to 16384 bytes by changing the DefaultReceiveWindow in the registry (http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-winsock-buffer.html)

```
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM \CurrentControlSet \Services \Afd \Parameters]
 DefaultReceiveWindow = 16384
 DefaultSendWindow = 16384
```

But there is no difference. I run on windows xp with pentium processor. Is there any other effective way to  make the image receiving faster?

EDIT:

This is the receiving code

```
Private Sub DataArrival(ByVal bytes As Long)

Dim str As String
' check the socket for data 
camera.GetData str
Dim str As String

While InStr(str, Terminator) <> 0

**Do some processing and put only the data in the variable str

 str = Mid(str, index, 1000)
 lImgSize = lImgSize + Len(str)
 strImg = strImg + str

  If lImageSize >= 1614414 Then
            Dim fileno As Integer
            fileno = FreeFile()
            Open ".\Imagefile.txt" For Output As #intFileNo
            Print #fileno , strImg
            Close #fileno 

  End If

End Sub
```

this is my other related question [How to read the end of image file stream in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220081/how-to-read-the-end-of-image-file-stream-in-vb6)

Comment: What operation limits your entire process speed? Is it network or CPU? You can check that easily - do not save and process image; how fast it can be received then? (BTW, VB6 can support multithreading, but it is so called apartment threading and doesn't help you much with parallel processing. Another question is, does your old? Pentium have multiple cores at all :))

Comment: @Arvo. It is a single core. and I think the CPU retricts the speed because my colleague was telling me that the program was working faster in a core 2 duo PC.

Comment: "each packet size is 8192 bytes": this is highly unlikely. In reality the actual IP packet size is more likely to be 1500 or less due to the path MTU. You're going to have to post some code to get further assistance.

Comment: Metrics like "I think" and "my colleague was telling" don't mean anything. Please measure network, saving  and processing times separately, then we can at least try to offer some solutions.

Comment: You're going to have to show us the receiving code before anyone can give a full answer. If it was a system issue then it would effect pretty much every network app. It's most likely a problem in your code.

Comment: 1.6MB seems large, have you considered compression?  To confirm I tested one VB6 program capturing from a USB webcam and streaming frames as JPEGs at 90% quality via TCP to a VB6 TCP client that displays them.  640x480 24-bit color at 15fps and no performance issues.  Only 75KB to 90KB per frame, which makes a huge difference.